# How to make two images with different heights the same height with the respect of ratio?

Tags: html, css

I googled everything and it seems that every example, every Stack Overflow answer doesn't work for me. I want to make two images the same height, I already made them the same width and I can make them the same height if I put for example `img {height: 400px;}` but I don't want that because the when the screen resolution is smaller or larger that can look bad.

And I saw that this can be fixed by using flex or grid but I really don't want to, I know that there is a small solution for this or a simple hack, but if everything else failed I guess I have to.

This is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
    .container {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    img {
     padding:3px;
     width: 49%;
     object-fit:cover;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

**EDIT: (added the links that I tried)**
[Two divs side by side - Fluid display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display)
[Two images, side by side responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997475/two-images-side-by-side-responsive)
[Two image on the same row and with the same height CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069614/two-image-on-the-same-row-and-with-the-same-height-css)
[How can I make all images of different height and width the same via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414856/how-can-i-make-all-images-of-different-height-and-width-the-same-via-css)
[CSS - Divs with same height, but different image heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627089/css-divs-with-same-height-but-different-image-heights)
[Making responsive images with different aspect ratios the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434523/making-responsive-images-with-different-aspect-ratios-the-same-height)
+ more.
some of them use flex others table others they set the height to a constant, that's not what I'm looking for.

**THANKS**

Comment: If you have looked at specific posts, best to mention them in your question and how they did not solve your problem, or your question will be closed as a duplicate. For instance, [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3971841/215552) has a number of CSS-only answers which don't use flexbox or grid...

Comment: the answers in that question are 90% in javascript and the remaining 10% didn't work for me, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Note I didn't say "for this specific question". I said "If you have looked at specific posts, best to mention them in your question and how they did not solve your problem, or your question will be closed as a duplicate." If you don't care if your question is closed as a duplicate, by all means, keep it as is.

Comment: I will edit the links that I tried, and plz don't close my question

Answer (score -2):

try using 'em' or 'rem.' Those adjust depending on the size of the window.

Comment: thanks, I learned something today but now when I try to resize the browser only the width  that changes, the height is constant.